# How to go about porting a Mac OSX game to Linux

Tags: linux, macos, cross-platform, porting

Any expert advice on how a beginner to porting might go about starting a project like this? Any porting guides or resources that might be helpful? Commonly used tactics?

My idea is to help make a game cross-platform compatible, but I don't know how to start going about it. The code is open source (anyone interested: https://github.com/prophile/xsera). It looks like it's written in C++ and uses Lua scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to suggest using SDL ([the Simple DirectMedia Layer](http://www.libsdl.org/)), which is a great cross-platform library for developing games that helps you with input events, graphics, audio, etc.  However, it looks as if the game you're porting is *already* based on SDL via a game engine called "Apollo", which is designed to be cross-platform:

> Apollo uses SDL and OpenGL for graphics and cross-platform compatibility, meaning that any game built on Apollo can run on Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux.

Have you tried contacting the authors to ask about the progress of a Linux port, and whether there's something in particular you can work on to help?  It sounds [from the FAQ](http://www.xsera.org/faq.htm#porting) as if there is some such effort under way, and you don't want to be duplicating effort needlessly.

In a hypothetical more difficult case, where you just have a pile of source code that was written with no eye on its possible portability,  I'd say that porting a game from one platform to another tends to be an iterative process of reading the source and prodding at it until it does what you want, involving:

- Understanding some part of the code (the crucial bit!)
- Trying to get it to compile
- `#ifdef`ing out parts that you won't need right at the moment
- Replacing low-level functionality with that from some thin cross-platform library
- Committing regularly
- Trying to avoid breaking anything on the existing supported platform

... and it's best if you at first try to just get *something* to work, which means putting even a basic build system in place, and so on.

However, since the original authors clearly intend this game to portable to Linux, it's should be much easier than that - how easy largely depends on your experience and enthusiasm for getting to grips with systems that you don't know.

Comment: Actually the original author wrote it for Classic Mac and this game is a port of it but right now the development is working mostly toward the Mac OSX version (I asked the devs about it and the game hasn't been tested on Linux).